# is there any way to export mysql boolean data as 'true' or 'false'

Tags: mysql, postgresql-9.1

I have a MySQL database and I want to import the data to PostgreSQL. The problem is when I export the source file as SQL dump then I need the boolean column as 'true' or 'false'. Is there any way to export it like or any way to import boolean values stored as `0` and `1` into PostgreSQL.

Comment: What do you get the boolean field as now?

Comment: if results are true then its shows 'b\'1\'' and blank when false

Comment: MySQL does not have a real boolean type, so it stores "booleans" as integers (0,1). The quickest way is probably to define the column as `integer` in Postgres and then later change that column to a real `boolean` using a type cast.

Answer (score 0):

You can import these and then change the type later.

See:

```
chris=> select 1::bool;
 bool 
------
 t
(1 row)

chris=> select 0::bool;
 bool 
------
 f
(1 row)

chris=> select 3::bool;
 bool 
------
 t
(1 row)
```